# How to find the "logged in user in windows" that is preventing a restart?

Tags: windows-10

Every time i try a restart a W10 Pro machine i admin there is always one "logged in user" who has forgotten to log out that prevents my update.

Is there a way i can see quickly who that user is and get them to log out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ctrl-alt-del and select "Task Manager"
Click "More details" at the bottom left
Select the "Users" tab

You will see a list of processes running on the machine organised by the owning User which will show you what other users are logged into the machine, and whether there are other applications or just background tasks.

If you right-click on a user (that is not your current logged-in user) you should see an option to "log out user" on the context menu that pops up.